# Data is passed as empty json array object in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am passing JSON data as a parameter to ajax call like

```
                  var startDate = dateFormatForSave($("#start_date").val().trim());
                  var arrayOfStudentsInfo = [];

                  var table = $("#selected_students");
                  table.find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
                        var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
                        var actualId = rowId.substr(rowId.indexOf("_") + 1).trim();
                        var routeId = $("#lockedRouteId_"+actualId).text().trim();
                        var stopId = $("#lockedStopId_"+actualId).text().trim();
                        var vehicleId = $("#lockedVehicleId_"+actualId).text().trim();

                        var innerArray =[];

                        innerArray["StudentId"] = actualId;
                        innerArray["RouteId"] = routeId;
                        innerArray["StopId"] = stopId;
                        innerArray["VehicleId"] = vehicleId;
                        innerArray["StartDate"] = startDate;

                        arrayOfStudentsInfo.push(JSON.stringify(innerArray));
                  });


                  $.ajax({
                         url: 'index.php?secController=TransportAllotment&action=saveAllotmentStudentWise',
                         type: 'POST',
                         dataType: 'JSON',
                         data: {
                             arrayOfStudentsInfo:  arrayOfStudentsInfo

                         },
                         success: function (data) {
                                showSwalPopupMessage(data['message'], data['title'], data['result'], true, '?secController=TransportAllotment&action=allotStudentWiseView');
                            }
                         });
                   }});
```

I am first collecting all the information in the table then creating a JSON object using an array from this information. When I debug the code, all the data are added to array successfully one by one. But when I check in network tab of inspect element the form data is passed like arrayOfStudentsInfo[]: []. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var innerArray =[];
> ```

That is an array.

Arrays are designed to store an ordered list of data with numeric indexes.

When `JSON.stringify` serializes an array, it will *only* look at numeric indexes.

`"StudentId"` and so on are not numbers.

If you want to use named properties, then an array is not the right tool.

Use an object instead.

```
var innerArray = {};
```

… and change the variable name!

---

You could simplify your code by assigning the data in the object literal instead of following it with a bunch of individual assignments.

```
var innerArray = {
    StudentId: actualId,
    RouteId: routeId,
    StopId: stopId,
    VehicleId: vehicleId,
    StartDate: startDate
};
```

---

Note that PHP has its own syntax for expressing complex data structures in a POST request.

If you pushed the object directly into `arrayOfStudentsInfo` then jQuery would serialise it in a format compatible with that, PHP would decode it automatically, and you could skip the manual JSON decoding step in your PHP.

Answer (score -2):

You should change - var innerArray =[]; to var innerArray ={};

It should work fine then.

Comment: There is no point in coming along 15 minutes after someone has said something and repeating it with all the explanation removed.